# Why do I need to convert to int[] for a byte[] in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, types

In my database I have a table with a TinyInt.  I'm doing DB first Entity Framework and the POCO representation of this makes it a byte, as expected.

So in C#, a very simplified version of my model would something like this:

```
public partial class DataType
{
    public byte DataTypeID { get; set; }
    public string DataTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to do a LINQ query to search for certain data types.  I have a byte array as part of my search parameters and do something like this:

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    public byte[] SearchIds;
}
```

And then I call it like this:

```
var parameters = new SearchParameters{SearchIds = new byte[]{1, 2, 3}};
_context.Items.Where(i=>parameters.SearchIds.Contains(i.DataTypeID)).ToList();
```

As soon as I try an enumerate my results with .ToList(), I get the error

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection
> ResultType.\r\nParameter name: input

After some searching around, I tried changing my search parameters to be an int[] instead of a byte[]

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    public int[] SearchIds;
}
```

and it now it magically started working.

WHY?

I don't understand *WHY* if I have a byte[] and am doing a search for another byte within it, WHY do I need to use (or convert to) an int?  I mean, I could understand if it could handle an int as an implicit conversion, but this is expressly requiring an int.  It makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Looks like you don't have to cast to an `int` at all, you can just use a `List<byte>` or `IEnumerable<byte>`. They likely have special code for `byte[]` due to databases' binary types.

Comment: Note that the "why" question is actually answered in a comment: "This is an issue we have in EF originated int he fact that we map byte[] to binary columns in the database, so when we see the byte[] in this expression we don't handle it correctly. "

Comment: Confirmed -- List<byte> works fine. Thanks for linking me over to that question/answer